# Find out if android java class is used inside a plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have a jar library for Android which can be used directly, or inside another wrapper such as PhoneGap or Xamarin.

Is there a reliable way to check the environment from a class inside that library, and report if the library is being used inside a wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

You could examine the stack trace to look for classes you know are associated with wrappers. For example:

```
String[] suspiciousPackages = {"com.wrapper.foo", "bar.baz.bazamm"};    

StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
for (StackTraceElement element : elements) {
  for (String s : suspiciousPackages) {
      if (element.getClassName().startsWith(s)) {
          // in a wrapper
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already thought of that (this is my "plan B"), but I'm not sure it's the right way (what if package name changes tomorrow?)

Comment: I'm not really sure how else you could do this. I'm pretty sure all approaches will be brittle to some extent.